# Get rank for non english keyword in a english site

Tags: seo, keywords, language

I'm trying to get to the first page of Google search for a keyword in swedish language but the site and it's content is in english.

What's my best option here to get to the first page? Will anchor backlinks help me or do I need to make a landing page in swedish?

Comment: `Because I'm Latin, sometimes I use a word in English while talking in Spanish.` Similar question above, you should find your answer there.